# Database connection class using c#

Tags: c#, database, class, connection, using

Here we are trying to create an Database connection class that can be used through out the entire project by just calling the object.
It will be so much useful for the developers who try to simplify their code and enhance their coding standards

Create a new class named DataObjectClass and provide the below code,

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Data.OracleClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.HttpContext;

public class DataObjectClass : IDisposable
{
    private string strCon;
    private OracleConnection objCon;
    private OracleTransaction objTrans;
    private string strErrorMessage = "";
    private int intRowsAffected = 0;
    private bool blnIsTransactionRequired = false;
    private bool blnIsTransactionAlreadyOn = false;
    private bool blnIsConnectionRequired = false;
    public object objOraDB;
    public static string ConnectionString;
    private decimal decCVConcurrentSeqId;
    private bool boolCVIsAvalabilityChecked = false;
    private bool boolCVIsTransactionLocked = false;
    string strCVQuery;
    static int decCVAutoUnlockDuration = 0;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);

    }
   
    public int RowsAffected
    {
        //Use this property to know how many records have been affected by Insert/Update/statement
        get { return intRowsAffected; }
    }

    public string ErrorMessage
    {
        //Use this property to know the error message in case of an exception
        get { return strErrorMessage; }
    }

    private OracleCommand BuildIntCommand(string storedProcName, IDataParameter[] parameters)
    {
        OracleCommand objCmd = BuildQueryCommand(storedProcName, parameters);
        return objCmd;
    }

    private OracleCommand BuildQueryCommand(string storedProcName, IDataParameter[] parameters)
    {
        try
        {
            OracleCommand objCmd = new OracleCommand(storedProcName, objCon);
            objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            foreach (OracleParameter parameter in parameters)
            {
                objCmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
            }
            return objCmd;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

    private OracleCommand BuildQueryCommand(string storedProcName)
    {
        OracleCommand objCmd = new OracleCommand(storedProcName, objCon);
        objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        return objCmd;
    }

    private OracleCommand BuildQueryCommandWithSQL(string SQLString)
    {
        OracleCommand objCmd = new OracleCommand(SQLString, objCon);
        objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        return objCmd;
    }
    
    private OracleCommand BuildQueryCommandWithSQL(string SQLString, IDataParameter[] parameters)
    {
        try
        {
            OracleCommand objCmd = new OracleCommand(SQLString, objCon);
            objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            foreach (OracleParameter parameter in parameters)
            {
                objCmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
            }
            return objCmd;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

   public DataTable getSQLDataTable(string SQLString)
    {
        intRowsAffected = 0;
        strErrorMessage = "";
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        OracleDataAdapter OracleDA = new OracleDataAdapter();
        try
        {
            if (!blnIsTransactionRequired)
            {
                objCon = new OracleConnection(strCon);
                objCon.Open();
                OracleDA.SelectCommand = BuildQueryCommandWithSQL(SQLString);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!blnIsTransactionAlreadyOn)
                {
                    objTrans = objCon.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
                    blnIsTransactionAlreadyOn = true;
                }
                OracleDA.SelectCommand = BuildQueryCommandWithSQL(SQLString);
                OracleDA.SelectCommand.Transaction = objTrans;
            }
            //OracleDA.Fill(dataTable)
            OracleDA.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            CVStTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;
            OracleDA.Fill(dataTable);
            CVEndTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;
            csApplicationDatabaseLogger(CVStTime, CVEndTime, "getSQLDataTable # " + SQLString);
            return dataTable;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            strErrorMessage = "Message :" + ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!blnIsTransactionRequired)
            {
                if ((objCon != null))
                {
                    objCon.Close();
                    objCon.Dispose();
                    objCon = null;
                }
            }
            OracleDA.Dispose();
            OracleDA = null;
        }
    }

    public DataTable getSQLDataTable(string SQLString, IDataParameter[] parameters)
    {
        intRowsAffected = 0;
        strErrorMessage = "";
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        OracleDataAdapter OracleDA = new OracleDataAdapter();
        try
        {
            if (!blnIsTransactionRequired)
            {
                objCon = new OracleConnection(strCon);
                objCon.Open();
                OracleDA.SelectCommand = BuildQueryCommandWithSQL(SQLString, parameters);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!blnIsTransactionAlreadyOn)
                {
                    objTrans = objCon.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
                    blnIsTransactionAlreadyOn = true;
                }
                OracleDA.SelectCommand = BuildQueryCommandWithSQL(SQLString, parameters);
                OracleDA.SelectCommand.Transaction = objTrans;
            }
            OracleDA.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            OracleDA.Fill(dataTable);
            return dataTable;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            strErrorMessage = "Message :" + ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!blnIsTransactionRequired)
            {
                if ((objCon != null))
                {
                    objCon.Close();
                    objCon.Dispose();
                    objCon = null;
                }
            }
            OracleDA.Dispose();
            OracleDA = null;       
        }
    }

    public DataRow getSQLDataRow(string SQLString)
    {
        intRowsAffected = 0;
        strErrorMessage = "";
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        OracleDataAdapter OracleDA = new OracleDataAdapter();
        try
        {
            if (!blnIsTransactionRequired)
            {
                objCon = new OracleConnection(strCon);
                objCon.Open();
                OracleDA.SelectCommand = BuildQueryCommandWithSQL(SQLString);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!blnIsTransactionAlreadyOn)
                {
                    objTrans = objCon.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
                    blnIsTransactionAlreadyOn = true;
                }
                OracleDA.SelectCommand = BuildQueryCommandWithSQL(SQLString);
                OracleDA.SelectCommand.Transaction = objTrans;
            }
            CVStTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;
            OracleDA.Fill(dataSet, 0, 1, "jay");
            CVEndTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;
            csApplicationDatabaseLogger(CVStTime, CVEndTime, "getSQLDataRow # " + SQLString);
            if ((dataSet != null) && dataSet.Tables.Count > 0 && dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                return dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0];
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            strErrorMessage = "Message :" + ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!blnIsTransactionRequired)
            {
                if ((objCon != null))
                {
                    objCon.Close();
                    objCon.Dispose();
                    objCon = null;
                }
            }
            OracleDA.Dispose();
            OracleDA = null;
        }
    }

    public int ExecuteSQL(string SQLString)
    {
        intRowsAffected = 0;
        strErrorMessage = "";
        OracleCommand objCmd = default(OracleCommand);
        try
        {
            if (!blnIsTransactionRequired)
            {
                objCon = new OracleConnection(strCon);
                objCon.Open();
                objCmd = BuildQueryCommandWithSQL(SQLString);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!blnIsTransactionAlreadyOn)
                {
                    objTrans = objCon.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
                    blnIsTransactionAlreadyOn = true;
                }
                objCmd = BuildQueryCommandWithSQL(SQLString);
                objCmd.Transaction = objTrans;
            }
            CVStTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;
            intRowsAffected = objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery;
            CVEndTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;
            csApplicationDatabaseLogger(CVStTime, CVEndTime, "ExecuteSQL # " + SQLString);
            return intRowsAffected;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            strErrorMessage = "Message :" + ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!blnIsTransactionRequired)
            {
                if ((objCon != null))
                {
                    objCon.Close();
                    objCon.Dispose();
                    objCon = null;
                }
            }
            if ((objCmd != null))
            {
                objCmd.Parameters.Clear();
                objCmd.Dispose();
                objCmd = null;
            }
        }
    }
 
    public int ExecuteSQL(string SQLString, IDataParameter[] parameters)
    {
        intRowsAffected = 0;
        strErrorMessage = "";
        OracleCommand objCmd = default(OracleCommand);
        try
        {
            if (!blnIsTransactionRequired)
            {
                objCon = new OracleConnection(strCon);
                objCon.Open();
                objCmd = BuildQueryCommandWithSQL(SQLString, parameters);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!blnIsTransactionAlreadyOn)
                {
                    objTrans = objCon.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
                    blnIsTransactionAlreadyOn = true;
                }
                objCmd = BuildQueryCommandWithSQL(SQLString, parameters);
                objCmd.Transaction = objTrans;
            }
            intRowsAffected = objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery;
            return intRowsAffected;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            strErrorMessage = "Message :" + ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!blnIsTransactionRequired)
            {
                if ((objCon != null))
                {
                    objCon.Close();
                    objCon.Dispose();
                    objCon = null;
                }
            }
            if ((objCmd != null))
            {
                objCmd.Parameters.Clear();
                objCmd.Dispose();
                objCmd = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public void BeginTransaction()
    {
        objCon = new OracleConnection(strCon);
        objCon.Open();
        blnIsTransactionRequired = true;
    } 

    public void CloseConnection()
    {
        if ((objCon != null))
        {
            objCon.Close();
            objCon.Dispose();
            objCon = null;
        }
    }

    private OracleCommand BuildQueryCommandForSQLWithParam(string SQLString, IDataParameter[] parameters)
    {
        try
        {
            OracleCommand objCmd = objCon.CreateCommand();
            var _with1 = objCmd;
            _with1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            _with1.CommandText = SQLString;
            _with1.Parameters.Clear();
            if ((parameters != null))
            {
                foreach (OracleParameter parameter in parameters)
                {
                    if (!objCmd.Parameters.Contains(parameter))
                    {
                        objCmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                    }
                }
            }
            return objCmd;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

And you can call these functions on other classes as given below

```
string strsql;
DataTable dtvalue;
DataObjectClass objdataclass;
strsql = "select * from tablle";
dtvalue = objdataclass.getSQLDataTable(strsql);
```

Comment: Did you have question?

Comment: Do you mean to share code this with the SO community?

Comment: You need to create an instance of the `DataObjectClass` before using it: `objdataclass = new DataObjectClass();`

Comment: As a side note: adopt the `params` keyword and you will be able to reduce the code nearly twice using declarations like `private OracleCommand BuildQueryCommand(string storedProcName, params IDataParameter[] parameters)`